# Write dictionary with numpy arrays to .csv

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I want to write resultfiles to .csv. I prepared a simple test example.

```
import numpy as np
data = {}
testdata = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

data['set1'] = {'a': testdata, 'b': testdata, 'c': testdata}
data['set2'] = {'a2': testdata, 'b2': testdata, 'c2': testdata}
data['set3'] = {'a3': testdata, 'b3': testdata, 'c3': testdata}
```

It would be great to get a result file like this:

[image]

Is there a simple way that you can recomment?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer Have you tried using the `csv` module? Try some examples, you should be able to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect headers and rows in separate data structures and then use `csv` module to write everything to an excel sheet. Also, the `data` dict needs to be converted to `OrderedDict` to maintain order of sequence.

**SourceCode**

```
import numpy as np
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import chain


data = {}

testdata = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
data = OrderedDict(data)


a = {'a': testdata, 'b': testdata, 'c': testdata}
b = {'a2': testdata, 'b2': testdata, 'c2': testdata}
c = {'a3': testdata, 'b3': testdata, 'c3': testdata}

#covert inner dict to OrderedDict
data['set1'] = OrderedDict(sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))
data['set2'] = OrderedDict(sorted(b.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))
data['set3'] = OrderedDict(sorted(c.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))  

#collect second header
header2 = [data.get(k).keys() for k in data.keys()]

#get number of repetitions for header1
header1_size = len(header2[0])

#get header1
header1 = sorted((data.keys())*header1_size)

#flatten list of list of header2
header2 = list(chain.from_iterable(header2))

#get rows from data dict
rows = zip(*[v2 for k1,v1 in data.items() for k2,v2 in v1.items() ]) 

#write header1,header2 and rows to excel /csv
with open('csvfile.csv','wb') as ofile:               
    wr = csv.writer(ofile, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow(header1)
    wr.writerow(header2)
    wr.writerows(rows)
```

**csvfile**
[image]